# multiprocessing using pathos ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pathos.helpers.mp

Tags: python, multiprocess, pathos

I wanted an alternative for multiprocessing and came across `pathos` I dug more and got one answer where the Author had provided code to user `multiprocess.Process`. But, I am getting the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathos.helpers.mp'

for code:

```
import pathos.helpers.mp.Process as prc
```

Also,
When I used

`from multiprocess.process import BaseProcess`

I am getting the following error in `p.start()`:

> self._popen = self._Popen(self)
>
> TypeError: _Popen() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I have tried installing from pip as well as from git using setup.py file, both the ways I am getting this error. I could have commented my problem in that problem thread only but I don't have 50 reputations.

Answer (score 1):

`mp` is not a module inside the [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/pathos/helpers/__init__.py) , hence `import pathos.helpers.mp.Process` won't work.

you can do it this way:

`from pathos.helpers import mp`

and call:

`mp.Process(target=foo, args=(x, y)).start()`